# Overriding inherited properties’ getters and setters in Python

Tags: python, properties

I’m currently using the `@property` decorator to achieve “getters and setters” in a couple of my classes. I wish to be able to inherit these `@property` methods in a child class.

I have some Python code (specifically, I’m working in py3k) which looks vaguely like so:

```
class A:
    @property
    def attr(self):
        try:
            return self._attr
        except AttributeError:
            return ''

class B(A):
    @property
    def attr(self):
        return A.attr   # The bit that doesn't work.

    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        self._attr = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    print('Before set:', repr(b.attr))
    b.attr = 'abc'
    print(' After set:', repr(b.attr))
```

I have marked the part that doesn’t work with a comment. I want the base class’ attr getter to be returned. `A.attr` returns a property object (which is probably very close to what I need!).

**Edit**:
After receiving the answer below from Ned I thought up what I think is a more elegant solution to this problem.

```
class A:
    @property
    def attr(self):
        try:
            return self._attr
        except AttributeError:
            return ''

class B(A):        
    @A.attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        self._attr = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    print('Before set:', repr(b.attr))
    b.attr = 'abc'
    print(' After set:', repr(b.attr))
```

The `.setter` decorator expects a property object which we can get using `@A.attr`. This means we do not have to declare the property again in the child class.

(This is the difference between working on a problem at the end of the day vs working on it at the beginning of the day!)

Comment: I had the same problem, and can confirm your answer works, but WOW what a $hitty "feature" - Adding the superclass name linkage!!!  That's a poor design on python's part.

Either that or "reimplement" the property.  Either are crappy "solutions" to inheritance.

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you for `@A.attr.setter`. I tried first `@super.attr.setter` this will not work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want:

```
class B(A):
    @property
    def attr(self):
        return super(B, self).attr
```

You mention wanting to return the parent class's getter, but you need to invoke the getter, not return it.

Comment: This doesn’t work for me, however, if I call `super().attr` I get the desired effect. Is that a wise thing to do?

Comment: Ah, you're right, because the parent's .attr is not available as an invokable getter any more, only as a property.  super() is the way to access same-named attributes from parent classes.  Why would it be an un-wise thing to do?

Comment: Just checking. I didn’t have a reason against. Update your reply to have `super().attr` instead of `super(B, self).attr()` and I’ll mark it as answered :) Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You got it! I'll do almost anything for that big green checkmark! :)

Comment: Although I did only use `super().attr` and not `super(B, self).attr`. Both seem to work, however.

Comment: This only shows the reading (getter). The writing (setter) stuff is missing.

Answer (score 43):

To override a setter in python 2 I did this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._attr = None

    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self._attr

    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        self._attr = value


class B(A):
    @A.attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        # Do some crazy stuff with `value`
        value = value[0:3]
        A.attr.fset(self, value)
```

To understand where `A.attr.fset` came from see the documentation on the `property` class:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Comment: Interestingly enough, `B` doesn't *have* to inherit the getter from `A`. If `B` only inherited from `object`, `B.attr.fget` will return `<function Foo.baz at 0x123456789>`. I was concerned that `A.attr.fset` has now been assigned a user-defined function. `A.attr.fset` is still `None`, while `B.attr.fset` is `<function B.baz at 0x987654321>`. So overriding any of the property's accessibility members, creates a copy of the property first. At least, that appears to be what is happening.

Comment: I especially like how you showed how to override just the setter. I didn't know how to do it and this gives me a little more insight into the setter decorator.

Comment: @TylerCrompton. That's the whole reason you have to do `@propertyname.setter`: properties are immutable objects, and normally, if you define a getter and a setter, you've made two property objects along the way, the first of which was discarded. I'm sure you realize this five years after the original comment, but I'll leave this here for posterity.

Comment: I often saw the convention that property getters have names such as `get_attr` and setters have names such as `set_attr`, and I follow this convention. However, when I test your code, it **only** works if the setter method in the child class `B(A)` has the same name as the property. In other words, if I replace `def attr(self, value)` with `def set_attr(self, value)` in your code, then it stops working (it doesn't override the parent class's property setter). This seems a bit counterintuitive. Is it a bug or not?

Comment: This works. However, if I also wanted to override parent's getter, adding something like `@A.attr.setter\\def attr(self)` doesn't work for some reason. If this comes after `@A.attr.setter` part, then the setter part is ignored. Vice versa. Why?

Comment: IDE complains that `value` in the last line `A.attr.fset(self, value)` is unexpected argument although the code runs fine. Why?