# Detect if super() has a function with decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, multiple-inheritance

I'm defining several classes intended to be used for multiple inheritance, e.g.:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, bacon = None, **kwargs):
        self.bacon = bacon
        if bacon is None:
            self.bacon = 100
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
class Bacon(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Optional: bacon"""
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Eggs(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Optional: bacon"""
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class Spam(Eggs, Bacon):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Optional: bacon"""
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

However, I have multiple classes (e.g. possibly `Bacon`, `A`, and `Spam`, but not `Eggs`) that care about when their property `bacon` is changed.  They don't need to modify the value, only to know what the new value is, like an event.  Because of the Multiple Inheritance nature I have set up, this would mean having to notify the super class about the change (if it cares).

I know that it might be possible if I pass the class name to the method decorator, or if I use a class decorator.  I don't want to have all the direct self-class referencing, having to create lots of decorators above each class, or forcing the methods to be the same name, as none of these sound very pythonic.

I was hoping to get syntax that looks something like this:

```
    @on_change(bacon)
    def on_bacon_change(self, bacon):
        # read from old/new bacon
        make_eggs(how_much = bacon)
```

I don't care about the previous value of `bacon`, so that bacon argument isn't necessary, if this is called after `bacon` is set.

- Is it possible to check if a super class has a method with this
  decorator?
- If this isn't feasible, are there alternatives to passing events like
  this, up through the multiple-inheritance chain?

**EDIT:**

The actual calling of the function in Spam would be done in A, by using a `@property` and `@bacon.setter`, as that would be the upper-most class that initializes `bacon`.  Once it knows what function to call on `self`, the problem only lies in propagating the call up the MI chain.

**EDIT 2:**

If I override the attribute with a `@bacon.setter`, Would it be possible to determine whether the super() class has a setter for `bacon`?

Comment: Apparently the OP means "{Detect if super() has a function} with a decorator", not "Detect if super() has a {function with a decorator}"

Comment: The `None` default is mainly used when you actually have to run something of interest to get the default. Here you can just use `def foo(self, bacon=100, **kwargs): self.bacon = bacon` although you should use `def __init__(self, **kwargs): self.bacon = kwargs.get('bacon', 100)` if you're trying to support shuffling around arbitrary kwargs to really please the OOP weenies.

Comment: @MikeGraham The bacon argument is there to strip it out of any passed `kwargs`, as I don't think the default `object` would be happy with it.  The intent is that every argument is stripped out of `kwargs` by the time it reaches `object`.

Comment: I had forgotten that newer versions of Python's `object.__init__` do not accept arbitrary arguments like they used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call for would probably be nicely fit with a more complete framework of signals, and so on - maybe even invite for Aspected Oriented Programing.

Without going deep into it however, a metaclass and a decorator can do just what you are asking for - I came up with these, I hope they work for you.

If you'd like to evolve this in to something robust and usable, write me - if nothing like this exists out there, it wouldbe worth to keep an utility package in pipy for this.

```
def setattr_wrapper(cls):
    def watcher_setattr(self, attr, val):
        super(cls, self).__setattr__(attr, val)
        watched = cls.__dict__["_watched_attrs"]
        if attr in watched:
            for method in watched[attr]:
                getattr(self, method)(attr, val)
    return watcher_setattr

class AttrNotifier(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, dct):
        dct["_watched_attrs"] = {}
        for key, value in dct.items():
            if hasattr(value, "_watched_attrs"):
                for attr in getattr(value, "_watched_attrs"):
                    if not attr in dct["_watched_attrs"]:
                        dct["_watched_attrs"][attr] = set()
                    dct["_watched_attrs"][attr].add(key)
        cls = type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, dct)
        cls.__setattr__ = setattr_wrapper(cls)
        return cls


def on_change(*args):
    def decorator(meth):
        our_args = args
        #ensure that this decorator is stackable
        if hasattr(meth, "_watched_attrs"):
            our_args = getattr(meth, "_watched_attrs") + our_args
        setattr(meth, "_watched_attrs", our_args)
        return meth
    return decorator

# from here on, example of use:
class A(metaclass=AttrNotifier):
    @on_change("bacon")
    def bacon_changed(self, attr, val):
        print ("%s changed in %s to %s" % (attr, self.__class__.__name__, val)) 


class Spam(A):
    @on_change("bacon", "pepper")
    def changed(self, attr, val):
        print ("%s changed in %s to %s" % (attr, self.__class__.__name__, val)) 

a = A()
a.bacon = 5

b = Spam()
b.pepper = 10
b.bacon = 20
```

(tested in Python 3.2 and Python 2.6 - changing the declaration of the "A" class for
Python 2 metaclass syntax)

**edit - some words on what is being done** 
Here is what happens:
The metaclass picks all methods marked with the "on_close" decorator, and register then in a dictionary on the class - this dictionary is named `_watched_attrs` and it can be accessed as a normal class attribute.

The other thing the metaclass does is to override the `__setattr__` method for the clas  once it is created. This new `__setattr__` just sets the attribute, and then checks the `_wacthed_attrs` dictionary if there are any methods on that class registered to be called when the attribute just changed has been modified - if so, it calls it.

The extra indirection level around `watcher_setattr` (which is the function that becomes each class's `__setattr__` is there so that you can register different attributes to be watched on each class on the inheritance chain - all the classess have indepently acessible  `_watched_attrs` dictionaries. If it was not for this, only the most specilized class on the inheritance chain `_watched_attrs` would be respected.

Comment: Gonna need to do some more investigation before I accept, all this meta and decorator and recursion stuff is overloading me at the moment. :P

Comment: There is no "recursion" in there :-) . It only looks complicated, actually -  I will write some explanatory text.

Comment: Infinite recursion was a separate issue, of an alternative method that I was attempting to think through before I saw your post, haha.

Thanks very much for the explanatory text, I think that will answer my question (though I may simplify it down to only support a single attribute).

Comment: Something else that exists, and provides similar functionality: [Decovent](http://packages.python.org/Decovent/)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for python *properties*:

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Search google for `override superclass property setter` resulted in this StackOverflow question:

[Overriding inherited properties’ getters and setters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336767/overriding-inherited-properties-getters-and-setters-in-python)

Comment: Were you perhaps referring to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9343762/936083)?  Would there be a way of doing this as a decorator, or a way to avoid having to directly reference the parent?

Comment: I don't think it would work for the case that `Spam` and `Bacon` have setters, but `Eggs` does not, as `Eggs` does not directly inherit from `Bacon`.