# Overwrite base class attribute with @property of the same name

Tags: python, properties, subclass

I am trying to subclass a python class and overwrite a regular attribute with a @property function. The catch is that I can't modify the parent class, and the api for the child class needs to look the same as the parent class (but behave differently). (So my question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336767/overriding-inherited-properties-getters-and-setters-in-python) in which the parent class also used a @property method to access the underlying attribute.)

The simplest possible example is

```
# assume this class can't be overwritten
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.attr = a

# how do I make this work?
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a):
        super(Child, self).__init__(a)

    # overwrite access to attr with a function
    @property
    def attr(self):
        return super(Child, self).attr**2

c = Child(4)
print c.attr # should be 16
```

This produces an error when the parent **init** method is called.

```
<ipython-input-15-356fb0400868> in __init__(self, a)
      2 class Parent(object):
      3     def __init__(self, a):
----> 4         self.attr = a
      5 
      6 # how do I make this work?

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Hopefully it is clear what I want to do and why. But I can't figure out how.

Comment: You need to write a setter for your property as well.  Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) on properties?  However, I don't think what you're attempting will work, since `self.attr` is stored on the instance, not the class, so using `super` in the way you seem to be trying won't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily fixed by adding a setter method

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._attr = None
        super(Child, self).__init__(a)

    # overwrite access to a with a function
    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self._attr**2

    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        self._attr = value
```