# Override both getter and setter of a property

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to override both getter and setter of a property in a subclass. Consider the following python3 code snippet:

```
class Base():
    @property
    def value(self):
        return "Base.value"

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        pass

class Child(Base):
    @Base.value.getter
    def value(self):
        return "Child.value"

    @Base.value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        pass

c = Child()
print(c.value)
```

This program prints `Base.value`, meaning that the `value` getter is not overridden. However if I remove the `value` setter in the `Child` class, the program prints `Child.value` which means the getter is overridden.

What is wrong with this way of overriding properties? Why does modifying the setter changes the behavior of the getter? And how can I correctly override both getter and setter in the subclass?

Comment: did you try looking here? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336767/overriding-inherited-properties-getters-and-setters-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding inherited properties’ getters and setters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336767/overriding-inherited-properties-getters-and-setters-in-python)

Comment: @WhatsThePoint & DevX: That is a different issue about calling the parent property in the child property. It does not address the problem I mention here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my observations, I think you are supposed to use the @Base.value.setter (or .getter) decorator if only the setter (or getter) needs to be overwritten.

If you have to override both, just use the usual @property approach.

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 'Value'

    @property
    def value(self):
        print('Base.Getter')
        return f'Base.{self._value}'

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        print('Base.Setter')
        self._value = value

class Child(Base):
    @property
    #@Base.value.getter
    def value(self):
        print('Child.Getter')
        return f'Child.{self._value}'

    @value.setter
    #@Base.value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        print('Child.Setter')
        self._value = value

b, c = Base(), Child()
print(b.value)
print(c.value)
b.value = 'test.base'
c.value = 'test.child'
print(b.value)
print(c.value)
```

prints:

```
Base.Getter
Base.Value
Child.Getter
Child.Value
Base.Setter
Child.Setter
Base.Getter
Base.test.base
Child.Getter
Child.test.child
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. So it seems the `Base.value.getter/setter` decorators are meant to somehow use properties from another class while redefining part of it, not to indicate inheritance. So in my example the setter definition will overwrite the `value` property with the `Base` getter and the new setter. Weird...